# packages accessed from base python even though virtualenv is active

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, virtualenv, modulenotfounderror

I have set up virtual env in Jupyter notebook, and here is the picture of Python and env used [python and installed package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vLlh.png).

Even though it says that package is installed it throws error `ModuleNotFound` when I import **spacy**.

But when I do `pip install spacy` in base Python, it works. Can someone please help me how to use modules from my virtualenv?

Comment: Try to deactivate the virtualenv and source it again. If that doesn't work, try removing the virtualenv and initializing it again.